# How To Reduce Dog Snoring

Tags: dogs, sleep, snoring

We have a 10 months old, very active Boston Terrier. He exercises everyday at least 30 minutes and it's not a problem to get him to sleep at night. 
The only issue we are having with him is that he snores a LOT and of course he sleeps in our bedroom. I can barely hear him snore (I'm a sound sleeper), but is keeping my husband awake and last night he had to sleep on the couch because of it. 
We also have three cats that sleep in the bedroom, the dog obviously wants to sleep with the rest of the family, so making him sleep outside would be our last resource.
Anyone has any experience with reducing the loudness of snoring on dogs or training a human to sleep with a snoring dog?

Comment: Is adding a sound like a TV or sound device to mask the snoring an option?

Comment: @JamesJenkins His snoring is so loud that if the TV volume was high enough to mask it then the TV wouldn't let you sleep. Picture a grown 80kg man snoring, really :)

Comment: @EliBud I have a Red Nose Pit bull and she snores a lot. If your dog is that loud then have your dog leave the room and sleep somewhere else in your house.

Comment: @PsychOPhobiA and anyone else interested in how this story ended: Now the dog sleeps downstairs :( It wasn't easy but we couldn't take it anymore and I can say he's the same merry puppy he was before, I even think he's more respectful now. Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Comment: Another update to this story, the dog learned to stop snoring! After we spent some nights with him in a beach house that had only a thin wall dividing the bedroom and living room, we started waking him up by saying his name when he was snoring. Well guess what, he learnt to stop snoring when he's sleeping and you call his name and also he has reduced his snoring to a minimum when he's in the bedroom with us, so now he's back sleeping in the bedroom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had experience with snoring dogs. When I exercise my dogs all day, especially right before bed, they tend to be so outrageously tired that they snore all night (but not too loudly that it keeps me up). My advice is to not exercise him extensively before bed, give him like an hour or so of rest. This way, when he sleeps, he isn't as tired when it is bed time. Then, hopefully, when he rests, he won't snore.

If your dog is on the heavier side, it could be due to excess tissue in their airway. One piece of advice given is to exercise them regularly, which will reduce weight and snoring. Check out this website: [6 ways to stop dog snoring](http://www.vetinfo.com/ways-stop-dog-snoring.html#b).

Snoring could also be caused by a cold or allergens. If it is allergens, make sure the bedding he sleeps on is clean and dust free. It may also just be the breed. Some breeds are more susceptible to snoring (like pugs or Boston terriers). In which case, it may be difficult to stop them from snoring.

PART 2 (ADDED):
Ok, so I researched more on Boston Terriers and their snoring habits. It is due to their breed and you can't do much about it. Check out this website: [Reduce Snoring](http://bostonterrierville.com/reduce-snoring-in-boston-terriers/). My advice after looking through this and other websites, is to change the position of how the dog sleeps. If the dog is laying on their back, then their snoring will be more noticeable. A recommendation is to get a round dog bed so they sleep in a ball -- which reduces snoring as there is less pressure on their throat in the night. However, I know you want the dog to sleep in the room with you, so I would make the dog move positions if the snoring is bothering you and attempt to train him to sleep on his side or stomach, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but he normally exercises early on the afternoon and he doesn't have any weight issues. Boston terriers are well known for their snoring but we never thought it could be so loud as to keep someone awake (he really snores like a big person).

Comment: @EliBud I researched more information on this breed and their snoring habits. I edited my answer and hopefully it helps you! If not, let me know and I can continue to research and help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if thread still open, but if your Boston is sleeping on or near wool, try a fleece blanket instead. This made a huge difference.

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! It's OK to add new answers to old questions. It can always help other people with the same problem. Do you perhaps know the _reason_ why this might help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a Boston Terrier who could snore so loud I could hear him in the living room from the bedroom.  Our vet suggested a children's antihistamine. He has passed away since and I have trouble sleeping without his snoring.  I thought of it as a white noise sound.

Comment: Did the antihistamine work?